# What does the "sudo" command do, and its usage mandatory?

Tags: command-line, root, tor

I run my terminal commands as root but sometimes some programs (e.g., Tor Browser) say "The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root. Exiting."

I want to understand whether this command is optional or mandatory (e.g., **`sudo`** `apt-get install tor`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run as root `sudo` is not necessary, if you run as normal user and want to do something which requires elevated privileges then you need it.

Beside the fact that you shouldn't run the whole time as root for various reasons, such as security etc. This is why the tor browser wont start when you run as root.

Sudo means "super user do" so you will only be root for that particular command. Sure the following commands containing `sudo` as long within a defined time-frame wont ask you for your password again, but there are ways to change that.

Answer (score 0):

It stands for "super user do" something.  It allows a certain set of permitted users to run as the root user (full access to everything).  So if your install through `apt-get` needs to modify something that only root can change, you need to use `sudo`.